# adding multiple column in table dynamicaly without using alter command in sql

Tags: mysql, database

I have to design a database in such a manner so that when ever i have to add or delete any column from the table i should not have to use **alter command** . Please guide me if it is possible to design a database like that

Comment: There is generally no way to add a column to a table without using `ALTER`.  Why do you have this requirement?  Typically, such changes would be made offline, outside of your application.

Comment: lets suppose a have to design a database for student information and i have created a table containing items like "name" "class" "roll_number"  after sometimes if requirement of "phone_number" is there then how can i design it at the first time only such that all the requirement is fullfilled without altering it.

Comment: You can't, not without either adding all possible columns you expect, or creating code which can use `ALTER` to add columns.

Comment: but if i have to consider all the possible column for the first time only then the database will be very large and some of the space might not be used also, so  is there any another way to design such database

Comment: Get your design down.  You do that by doing a good job to gather requirements.  If your requirements are so vague that you need to ask this question, then I could argue that you aren't even ready to begin creating your actual database.

Comment: You *might* want to look at an EAV model instead